# Javascript gives different timezone on the same machine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date

The google chrome console is returning different timezones if I initialize the Date with a parameter or not.

[image: javascript dates]
In another machine the same code give me the right result:

[image: javascript dates]
It's weird but it's happening

Comment: Not sure I understand - you're showing a perfectly reasonable result on two different computers, and today is definitely not November 15th, so the fact that `new Date()` and `new Date(a date in november)` give you different values makes sense. As for the timezone: your input string doesn't say which timezone to use, so JS is quite literally free to pick any timezone it wants. Don't use `Z` if you want BST?

Comment: Should the JS choose the client timezone? In the second Image I pass the same November Date but it return the machine timezone, and in the first one, the JS choose the daylight summer time from my region (Brasilia)

Comment: JS picks "whatever the browser is set to make it do", and there are all kinds of different settings that will change what it ends up using. It might even decide that, in order to honour your security or tracking settings, you don't even _have_ a timezone, and `new Date()` ends up being January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: Of course the real answer here is "use a datetime library like moment.js" because localisation is hard, and dates are hard, and together they're even harder, and you should rely on many others already having made sure to account for all the craziness when working with dates.

Comment: Different version of Chrome might regards or not dailiight shifting. Check version of Crome on both machines

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is related to system configuration, not javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume is Daylight Savings Time (DTS).

As it seems from the logs, the computers are not in the same location, and it seems that in Brazil, [DTS is adopted regionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Brazil#Regional_applicability), applicable at the beginning of November.

A quick way to test if this is true, try creating an October date instead of November.

Comment: You're right. I initialized a new Date in July and get the right timezone. So, the problem is the second image, where I initialize a November Date and don't get the DST. Probably the Ubuntu servers (Second image) don't know this and the Windows server does (First image).

Comment: By reading the wiki page, there are too a lot of parameters and changes on how Brazil adopts DTS so one of the sources might have given up on supporting it.

Comment: Yeah, actually this year is the first without the DST, it was cancelled.